# Opa eval command line - always evaluates to false

Tags: opa

Attempting to evaluate opa via command line but for some reason the evaluation output is always set to false.  In this case, the rego policy is just validating the input checking if the RoleID has access to the table.

policy.rego

```
package play
import data.Roles

default access = false
access {
    some i,j
    currentRole = Roles[i]
    currentRole.RoleID == input.RoleID
    currentRole.tables[j] == input.tableName
}
```

data.json

```
{
  "Roles": [
    {
      "RoleID": "SalesHead",
      "tables": [
        "APAC-Sales",
        "USA-Sales"
      ]
    },
    {
      "RoleID": "AccountsHead",
      "tables": [
        "APAC-Accounts",
        "USA-Accounts"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

test.json (input)

```
{
  "input": {
    "RoleID": "SalesHead",
    "tableName": "USA-Sales"
  }
}
```

Command:

```
opa eval --data policy.rego --input test.json --format raw "data.play"
```

Output:

```
{"access":false}
```

^^^This should be: {"access":true}

Stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Had to remove input key from input.json
Resolved